# Want to port existing rsync on windows

Tags: windows, rsync, msys, mingw-w64

I know currently there is rsync for windows available as G-Rsync.
That is this :- http://sourceforge.net/projects/grsync-win/

But, what I want to do is just make existing rsync code available from here :-
https://rsync.samba.org/download.html 
to be run on windows.

I have checked :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528298/rsync-for-windows
but, that is not what I want.
Also, I have found https://github.com/MatthewSteeples/rsync.net
rsync port to .net.

Also, windows use WinSock instead of socket system call (so, I cannot write entire rsync for windows from scratch).
So, I have checked MingW-w64 here:- 
http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net

I guess there must be some method to port existing rsync code to windows.
Also, this following link doesn't help me :- 
[Technical Hurdles for Win32 rsync port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463/technical-hurdles-for-win32-rsync-port)

I am not very sure would this MingW-w64 help me.Can I use this tool to port existing rsync on windows. 
I also want to know , what does MingW-w64 is used for? 
Also , please bring to my notice if I am missing anything here.

**[Edit]**
I found these projects

1. https://github.com/meeuw/rsync-mingw32
   (can't find documentation for this project, readme.txt is same as rsync's).
2. http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Extension/rsync/rsync-3.0.8-1/
   (this needs MSYS console to configure MSYS-build-rsync).

but,can't figure out whether these options will serve my purpose?

can anyone please comment what is these above mentioned 2 projects about?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rsync was designed and built for Unix-y (POSIX compliant) systems. Windows is not a POSIX compliant Unix system. That is why you can't build the source code directly on Windows.

It depends on your application as to what you are trying to achieve but I think you have found the two main POSIX layers for Windows (Cygwin and MinGW). Those two POSIX layers add a level of POSIX compliance on top of standard Windows. This allows applications such as rsync to be easily ported to run on Windows.

So to answer your original question: if you want to port rsync to Windows then you will need to either rewrite large portions of rsync or use a POSIX compliance layer such as Cygwin or MinGW.

Comment: For current versions of Windows 10 you can now also use the new Windows Linux subsystem called "Bash for Windows". It runs native Linux ELF binaries and therefore rsync.

Comment: Another (and more effective, more compliant) layer of POSIX now is present, although in pre-alpha: it's called [Midipix](https://www.luciaillanes.de/en/projects#:~:text=Midipix%5B1%5D,of%20this%20process%3A)